# Faceted Search with Solrnet

Tags: solrnet, facet

Loving Solrnet, it is great.

I have successfully created a Solrnet search that returns facets.

```
articles = solr.Query(new SolrQuery(sQuery), new QueryOptions
        {
        Facet = new FacetParameters
        {
          Queries = new[] { new SolrFacetFieldQuery("content_type") }
        },
        Highlight = new HighlightingParameters
        {
          Fields = new[] { "description" },
          Snippets = 4,
          MaxAnalyzedChars = 10000,
        },
        Rows = sr.recordsPerPage,
        Start = pageI,
   });
```

Now I need to perform a Solrnet search when the user clicks on a individual facet, and they then go on to click more facets as the results narrow?  How is that done with the Solrnet API?  Do you use Filters?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/Sample-application.md

Answer (score -1):

I build query strings for each of the following fields below...

```
Queries = new[] { 
   new SolrFacetFieldQuery("content_type"), 
   new SolrFacetFieldQuery("subject"), new SolrFacetFieldQuery("category"), 
   new SolrFacetFieldQuery("timestamp")
},
```